# soapUI load test script not getting terminated

Tags: soapui

I am using soapUI 4.5.1 version on a Mac to perform some load tests. I have a load test setting with thread count as 100 and limit as 900 seconds. I have checked box to stop the script once time limit is reached. It worked perfectly fine.

Now I increased my thread count to 200 and the started the script. Please note, I am executing the scripts from command line using ./loadrunner.sh script. The script started executing but after 900 seconds it did not get terminated by itself. In fact it is not getting terminated.

Could you someone help me with this.

I tried to run my test in loadrunner but loadrunner has some java issues in mac and it is not getting started.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sometime the test continues to run a little beyond the time limit you have set as it needs to finish all the things it was doing before stopping the test.

So my question to you is how long did it run after 900 seconds?

If you are not tied to soapUI, give JMeter or loadUI a go. I have found JMeter to be more reliable than soapUI or loadUI.

What error are you getting on loadrunner?

ps: I have used soapUI on windows only!

Comment: Thank you for response. I totally forgot what issue I had at this point of time. I am using JMeter now. Thanks again for your time.